# React hooks app saga use history.push then doesn't render component correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga, history.js

Thanks for looking this quesion.  I use typescript to write a react hooks login demo.I have some question.
1. I use `history.push('/home')` when login success. but the page render a `Notification`component.
2. It's a better way to do router jump in login saga? Other way is do it in Login component.when success.use `useHistory` hook to do it.I prefer the first way to do it. I am a backend programmer new come to write frontend.so i don't know what is the best way.

The `services/history.ts`

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

My router

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loading from '@components/Loading';
import history from '@services/history';
import routes from './routes';

const renderRoutes = routes.map(({ path, exact, component, key }) => (
  <Route exact={exact || false} path={path} key={key} component={component} />
));

const Routers: React.FC = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Switch>{renderRoutes}</Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);

export default Routers;

// my routes
import { lazy } from 'react';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    key: 'login',
    exact: true,
    component: lazy(() => import('./../views/login')),
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    key: 'home',
    component: lazy(() => import('./../views/home')),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

my login.tsx

```js
const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (values: any) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const { username, password } = values;
    dispatch(loginRequest(username, password));
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-page">
      <Form name="login" className="login-form" onFinish={handleSubmit}>
        <p className="login-title"> Go React</p>
        <FormItem
          name="username"
          rules={[
            { required: true, message: 'Please input your Username!' },
            { min: 4, message: 'min length of username is 4' },
            { max: 12, message: 'max length of username is 12' },
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
            placeholder="Username"
            size="large"
          />
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem
          name="password"
          rules={[
            { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' },
            { min: 4, message: 'min length of password is 4' },
            { max: 12, message: 'max length of password is 12' },
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            size="large"
          />
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem>
          <Button
            htmlType="submit"
            type="primary"
            className="login-button"
            size="large"
          >
            <Spin indicator={antIcon} spinning={loading} />
            {loading ? ' Logging in' : ' Login'}
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

handlesubmit will send a dispatch, the saga will watch this.
saga.ts

```js
import { fork, all, take, call, put, cancel } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { message } from 'antd';
import fetchLogin from '@services/login';
import TokenStorage from '@utils/storage';
import ILoginResponseData from '@models/login';
import UserModel from '@models/user';
import history from '@services/history';
import {
  loginFailed,
  loginSuccess,
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILED,
} from './action';

function* LoginRequestSaga(username: string, password: string) {
  try {
    const result: ILoginResponseData = yield call(
      fetchLogin,
      username,
      password
    );
    if (result.code === '1') {
      TokenStorage.storeToken(result.token);
      message.success(result.msg);
      history.push('/home');         <-------------I do history jump in here.
      const user = UserModel.getUser(result.token);
      yield put(loginSuccess(user));
    } else {
      message.error(result.msg);
      yield put(loginFailed());
    }
  } catch (err) {
    message.error(err);
    yield put(loginFailed());
  }
}

function* watchLogin() {
  while (true) {
    const { authData } = yield take(LOGIN_REQUEST);
    const task = yield fork(
      LoginRequestSaga,
      authData.username,
      authData.password
    );
    const action = yield take([LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILED]);
    if (action.type === LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
      yield cancel(task);
    }
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([watchLogin()]);
}
```

My home component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '@store/reducer';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
  return <div>Current User:{user.name}</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

when login success. the page doesn't show correctly component.

[image]

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/store": "^2.0.2",
    "antd": "^4.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-rewire-alias": "^0.1.6",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the redux-saga part, but typically the `history` object is ***the one*** provided from the `Router` context, i.e. by either using the `useHistory` hook, or wrapping the component with `withRouter`. Alternatively I've use `connected-react-router` to place the router history object into your redux store and use dispatched actions to instead navigate. You didn't mention though if your code is working or not, are you just asking about what *may* be a better way? Such questions tend to result in opinionated responses. Based on the screenshot I guess the navigation fails.

Comment: @DrewReese  connected-react-router can work with react-router-dom v5.2.0?

Comment: Looks like it does! Supports react-router-dom v4/v5 https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router and the fourth feature bullet point says it works with redux-saga.

Comment: @xiaodonghuan Please share your package.json file or history package version.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal I had added it.

Comment: @DrewReese  I had try it yesterday...but failed.

Comment: From what I recall it did/does have a somewhat tedious setup, but the docs were clear enough to get through. This is probably a separate SO issue/conversation, but what was failing for you?

Comment: @DrewReese The answer of @pulkit-aggarwal works. I want to know what is different between use connected-react-router and use `history`? seems like i used the connected-react-router failed yesterday also cause by history package version? I will retry it .

Comment: Interesting, I'm still on history v4.7.2, react-router-dom v4.3.1, redux v4.0.0, and react-redux v6.0.0... guess I'm behind in versions a bit. Great that it is resolved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xiaodonghuan. There are some breaking changes in the newest version "5.0.0" of history package. For now, you can change its version to a stable version i.e. "4.10.1" which will work.

Use bellow command for change history version

```
npm install history@4.10.1
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: thanks. it works. where can i find break change issues about history 5.0? I check the history package issues. doesn't find related issue.

Comment: @xiaodonghuan https://www.npmjs.com/package/history#documentation Looks like history v5 is compatible with react-router v6, while history v4 with react-router v4/v5. https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/releases